# Using cayenne in Axis2 service : cannot find cayenne.xml

Tags: apache-axis, apache-cayenne

I'm trying to use `cayenne` within an `Axis2` service (compiled as an .aar file).

I was able to make the service locate my `cayenne` jar but when I try to make a query on the database, it throws the following exception:

> 2013-01-15 17:52:38,891 [http-8080-Processor25] DEBUG
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet  -
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: [v.3.0.2 Jun 11 2011 09:52:20] Error
>   during Configuration initialization. [v.3.0.2 Jun 11 2011 09:52:20]
>   [org.apache.cayenne.conf.DefaultConfiguration] : Domain configuration
>   file "cayenne.xml" is not found.

I've been trying to put the `cayenne.xml` file everywhere (`/lib /WEB-INF/lib /WEB-INF/classes` though I only had hope for the first one).

Could someone please advise me on how to proceed?

Is it possible to force cayenne to look for the cayenne.xml file in the `/lib directory` of my `.aar` ?

Is it possible to print the classpath that is used by the service's classLoader (I understand that each service should have its own classLoader).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am no Axis2 expert, from my theoretical understanding of its class loading mechanism, I see two options:

1. Ensure that cayenne-server.jar and cayenne.xml are loaded by the same ClassLoader (cayenne-server.jar should be in /WEB-INF/lib, while cayenne.xml - in /WEB-INF/classes/),
2. Set current thread classloader in your Axis code in the place where you bootstrap Cayenne, so that DefaultConfiguration could locate the XML files:

   Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());

Comment: .aar archives don't have a WEB-INF folder. At their root, you can put a lib folder to put your external jars in but without doing anything else, putting a classes folder doesn't solve the problem. I will try the 2. point and come back with the results. Thanks!

Comment: I managed to make it work by adding the said line before creating the datacontext and by putting the needed xml files (cayenne.xml, xx.map.xml and xx.driver.xml) at the root of the aar file! Thanks a lot!